# Numbers of choosing

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have 6 fruit 2 red 2 black and 2 white in how many ways can we choose 3 fruits  and put them in 3 diffrent boxes( ofcourse a box must contain only 1 fruit)

Comment: Are the boxes different?

Comment: yes they are diffrent one item in one box

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you had three of each, you could just put whatever color you want in each box.  How many ways is that?  As you have only two of each, subtract the choices where each box gets the same color.  How many is that?

Comment: 3! . 6 . 4 . 2?

Comment: No. Assuming the fruit of one color are identical, you have three choices for each box

Comment: We have 6 choices for the first ,4 for the second and 2 for the last.Now since they are arranged we can change the boxes just permutating the 3 of them which is 3!

Comment: As I read the problem the boxes are labeled.  You choose a fruit for box A. There are only three choices, because the two red fruit are interchangeable.  Then you choose a fruit for B. Again there are three choices.  Then you choose a fruit for C.  The difficulty is that there might still be three choices (if you chose different colors for A and B) or there might be only two.  My hint is one way to deal with that.

Comment: After you choose the first fruit you can put it everywhere(3 choices) then the second you have 1 box with fruit which means you have 2 .There is no :type of fruits in type of box every kind of fruit can be in any box there aren't limits

Comment: You are overcounting.  I can choose a red for A, then black for B, then white for C.  You would count separately white for C, black for B, red for A (and four more).  That is why I fill the boxes in a given order.